# Preventing unauthorized access to APIs

Tags: architecture

I have an application which calls various services to load data(of different entities shown in the web page). Opening the network tab in Chrome can tell me which APIs are being called. Now this can be used by other users to get the data, say calling the same API endpoint in another tab. I do not want the users to be able to do that. I want some way where my API returns data only when my application  calls it and not when directly called from browser or postman. 
Is it possible? If yes, how do I achieve the same?

Comment: The answer from Telastyn is correct.  You can't prevent this.  Chrome even provides the exact curl command to replicate the call you are making from within the web page.  Given that, if you explain more about what specifically you want to prevent the user from doing, you might get more help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Remember that it's not *your application* calling the API, it is Chrome or Edge or whatever browser is running the app. Once the code is on a user's machine they can exploit that to do whatever they want.

If you want to constrain access to an API you'll need to either require cryptographic keys or limit network access. Neither of which is viable if you want users to access the API from their machines via some "legitimate" means.